# ZF2, Doctrine2, Gedmo - SoftDelete JTI Entity with associations

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to soft delete a complete `Customer`. A `Customer` extends `User`. `Customer` also has associated `InvoiceAddress[]` entities.

It however, does not work. If the `Customer` has `@Gedmo\SoftDeleteable`, it fails on the Foreign Key association with `User`. If I also make the `User` entity soft delete-able, then it fails on the association between `Customer` and `InvoiceAddress`.

If I make the relation between `Customer` and `InvoiceAddress` to `cascade={"persist", "remove"}` (added `remove`), then it hard deletes all entities related to the `Customer`.

I figure it might be something in the configuration, though having [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562547/softdelete-functionality-in-doctrine2-using-gedmo-extension) [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798674/config-entries-for-doctrineextensions-softdeleteable-gedmo-doctrine-extensions) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841102/how-to-configure-doctrine-extensions-in-zend-framework-2) and (of course) [the docs](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/softdeleteable.md) of the SoftDeleteable extension itself, I haven't figured out what/where I'm doing something wrong.

Below is my setup, I've removed stuff from the code unrelated to the question.

**`Customer`.php**

```
namespace Customer\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteable;
// moar

/**
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 *
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
class Customer extends User implements SoftDeleteable
{
    use GedmoDeletedAtTrait;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection|InvoiceAddress[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Customer\Entity\InvoiceAddress", mappedBy="customer", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
     */
    protected $invoiceAddresses;

    // properties, __construct(){}, getters/setters...
}
```

**`User`.php**

```
namespace User\Entity;

use BjyAuthorize\Provider\Role\ProviderInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Mvc\Entity\AbstractEntity;
use ZfcUser\Entity\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 *
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 */
class User extends AbstractEntity implements UserInterface, ProviderInterface
{
    // properties, constructor, getters/setters... 
}
```

**`GedmoDeletedAtTrait`.php**

```
namespace Mvc\Traits;

use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Traits\SoftDeleteableEntity;

trait GedmoDeletedAtTrait
{
    use SoftDeleteableEntity;

    /**
     * Note: overrides Annotation (column name) and type hint, else it's the same as the original
     *
     * @var \DateTime|null
     * @Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $deletedAt;
}
```

**doctrine module config for Customer module**

```
'doctrine' => [
    'driver' => [
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => [
            'class' => 'Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\Driver\\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => [
                __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'src'
                . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Entity',
            ]
        ],
        'orm_default'             => [
            'drivers' => [
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'eventmanager' => [
        'orm_default' => [
            'subscribers' => [
                SoftDeleteableListener::class,
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

---

Related question: [the docs](http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/softdeleteable.html#usage) also mention "filters". How to implement them and use them throughout a module with the setup above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I was missing a piece of configuration, not (yet) sure as to how it relates to the Listener and the LifecycleCallbacks that need to be executed to soft-delete an Entity, but the complete configuration is as follows:

```
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter;
use Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\SoftDeleteableListener;

[ ... ]

'doctrine' => [
    'driver' => [
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => [
            'class' => 'Doctrine\\ORM\\Mapping\\Driver\\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => [
                __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'src'
                . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Entity',
            ]
        ],
        'orm_default'             => [
            'drivers' => [
                __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'eventmanager' => [
        'orm_default' => [
            'subscribers' => [
                SoftDeleteableListener::class,
            ],
        ],
    ],
    // THIS IS THE PART THAT WAS MISSING
    'configuration' => [
        'orm_default' => [
            'filters' => [
                'soft-deletable' => SoftDeleteableFilter::class,
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

In the above snipped I've marked the missing piece with a comment. However, as that bit just sets a filter to use on an alias, I'm not sure how it relates to the configuration above, which defines a Listener.

If I figure it out later/in the future I might come back and update this answer. In the mean time, maybe someone else might place a comment with the info?